# traefik using letsencrypt not routing to my services

Tags: ssl, docker-compose, ssl-certificate, traefik, lets-encrypt

This is my first time using **traefik** and **letsencrypt**, in this case I am just using it to provide **secure http** to my website, after struggling to string them up together using **docker compose**, I discover the lock icon(indicating the site is secure is shown in my browser) but  the web application traefik is suppose to route to is not run, instead a
**"Gateway Timeout"** text is written to the browser.

here are the setup files.

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.7.12
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - web
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - ./acme.json:/acme.json
    container_name: traefik
    environment:
      - "GODADDY_API_KEY=my-godaddy-api-key"
      - "GODADDY_API_SECRET=my-godaddy-api-secret"

  server:
    container_name: my-server
    image: my-server-image
    expose:
      - "8000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - uploadedFiles:/app/uploaded_files/
    environment:
      host_server: db
      db_server_port: 5432
      database_name: mydatabase
      db_username: myuser
      db_password: mypassword
      ssl_mode: prefer
    labels:
      - "traefik.docker.network=web"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.basic.frontend.rule=Host:mydomain.com"
      - "traefik.basic.port=8000"
    networks:
      - postgresqlnet
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - database
```

traefik.toml

```
debug = false

logLevel = "ERROR"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "mydomain.com"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = false

[acme]
email = "email@mydomain.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
caServer = "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"
  [acme.dnsChallenge]
  provider = "godaddy"
  delayBeforeCheck = 0
  [[acme.domains]]
```